# EF 6.2 Referential constraint Issue

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I created a SQLite 3 db from an existing SQL Express DB. The primary keys in the new SQLite db are type INTEGER, the foreign keys are type int. EF throws a 13101 error.
Example

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    TestID       INTEGER        NOT NULL,
    TestName     NVARCHAR (50),
    TestTypeId   INT,
    TestConfigId INT,
    Description  NVARCHAR (255),
    NumberOfRuns INT,
    Modified     ROWVERSION     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Tests PRIMARY KEY (
        TestID
    ),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        TestConfigId
    )
    REFERENCES TestConfiguration (TestConfigID) ON DELETE NO ACTION
                                                ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        TestTypeId
    )
    REFERENCES TestType (TestTypeID) ON DELETE NO ACTION
                                     ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE TestType (
    TestTypeID   INTEGER       NOT NULL,
    TestTypeName NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    Description  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    Modified     ROWVERSION    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_TestTypes PRIMARY KEY (
        TestTypeID
    )
);
```

In table Test, TestTypeId is an int and a FK, but in table TestTypes TestTypeID is an INTEGER and EF 6.2says they are of different types.

So is the answer to change all the PK's to int and make them AUTO_INCREMENT or change all the PK's to INTEGER?

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: We can't decide for you if making a *functional* change (AUTO_INCREMENT) is the way to go. I'd say, do whatever works best.

Comment: @Gert
Thanks! I may try both ways if I have time. Right now I am leaning to make everything INTEGER.